# Лагает при скролле RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Вообщем проблема такая, есть `TabLayout` и `ViewPager`, всего вкладок у меня 5, на первых двух вкладках идет `RecyclerView` с данными, а на 3 избранные, по началу там пустой адаптер.

Так вот, заполняю `RecyclerView` на первых двух фрагментах, и при скролле видно что лагает, просто я сравниваю с другим `RecyclerView` который не в фрагменте, а в `AppCompatActivity` там все идеально крутится, хотя там элементов больше и в адаптере условий больше, туда пользователь попадает нажав в первой или во второй вкладке на любой `item`. В первой вкладке у меня элементов где-то 100-150, во второй 30.

Из за чего может лагать скролл в `RecyclerView`, перепробывал все методы, даже ставил вместо `RecyclerView`, `ListView`, такая же байда. Думаю это связано с `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` ибо не в фрагменте так не лагает, сталкивались ли вы с такой проблемой? Подскажите в чем проблема?

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context ctx;
private List<myItem> objects = new ArrayList<>();
private List<myItem> originalObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private List<myItem> tempObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private String from;

public myAdapter(Context ctx, List<myItem> objects, String from){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.originalObjects = objects;
    this.from = from;
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    editor = sp.edit();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvNumber1;
    TextView tvText1;
    TextView tvText2;
    TextView tvText3;
    TextView tvNumber2;
    TextView tvPlace;
    CheckBox cbFav;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvNumber1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber1);
        tvText1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText1);
        tvText2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText2);
        tvText3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText3);
        tvNumber2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber2);
        tvPlace = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPlace);
        cbFav = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbFav);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_view, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myItem item = (myItem) v.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), two_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
            parent.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

public myItem getItem(int position){
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tvNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(objects.get(position).getId()));
    holder.tvPlace.setText(objects.get(position).getPlace());
    holder.tvNumber2.setText(String.valueOf(objects.get(position).getNumber2()));

    holder.tvNumber1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), sp.getString(Config.SP_FONT_NUMBER_1, Config.FONT_GOTHICB)));
    holder.tvNumber1.setTextColor(sp.getInt(Config.SP_COLOR_NUMBER_1, 0xffff0000));
    holder.tvNumber1.setTextSize(sp.getInt(Config.SP_SIZE_NUMBER_1, 22));

    holder.tvPlace.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Config.FONT_GOTHIC));
    holder.tvNumber2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), Config.FONT_GOTHIC));

    if (sp.getBoolean(Config.SP_SHOW_TEXT_1, true)){
        holder.tvText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvText1.setText(objects.get(position).getText1());
        holder.tvText1.setTextSize(sp.getInt(Config.SP_SIZE_TEXT_1, 22));
        holder.tvText1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), sp.getString(Config.SP_FONT_TEXT_1, Config.FONT_1)));
        holder.tvText1.setTextColor(sp.getInt(Config.SP_COLOR_TEXT_1, 0xff000000));
    } else {
        holder.tvText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (sp.getBoolean(Config.SP_SHOW_TEXT_2, true)){
        holder.tvText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvText2.setText(objects.get(position).getText2());
        holder.tvText2.setTextSize(sp.getInt(Config.SP_SIZE_TEXT_2, 18));
        holder.tvText2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), sp.getString(Config.SP_FONT_TEXT_2, Config.FONT_GOTHICB)));
        holder.tvText2.setTextColor(sp.getInt(Config.SP_COLOR_TEXT_2, 0xff000000));
    } else {
        holder.tvText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (sp.getBoolean(Config.SP_SHOW_TEXT_3, true)){
        holder.tvText3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tvText3.setText(objects.get(position).getText3());
        holder.tvText3.setTextSize(sp.getInt(Config.SP_SIZE_TEXT_3, 18));
        holder.tvText3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), sp.getString(Config.SP_FONT_TEXT_3, Config.FONT_GOTHIC)));
        holder.tvText3.setTextColor(sp.getInt(Config.SP_COLOR_TEXT_3, 0xff000000));
    } else {
        holder.tvText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.cbFav.setChecked(isFav(objects.get(position)));
    holder.cbFav.setTag(objects.get(position));
    holder.cbFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myItem item = (myItem) view.getTag();
            setFav(ctx, item);
            if(from.equals("FAV")){
                objects.remove(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
    holder.itemView.setTag(objects.get(position));
}

private boolean isFav(myItem item){
    boolean isFav = false;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sp.getString(Config.SP_FAV, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myItem>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<myItem> arrayList;
    if (json == null) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
    if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (arrayList.get(i).getId() == item.getId()) {
                isFav = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isFav;
}

private void setFav(Context ctx, myItem item){
    boolean isFav = false;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sp.getString(Config.SP_FAV, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<myItem>>() {}.getType();
    ArrayList<myItem> arrayList;
    if (json == null) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
    if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (arrayList.get(i).getId() == item.getId()) {
                isFav = true;
                arrayList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isFav){
        arrayList.add(item);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.added_to_favorites, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, R.string.removed_from_favorites, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    String toJson = gson.toJson(arrayList);
    editor.putString(Config.SP_FAV, toJson).apply();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            tempObjects = new ArrayList<>();

            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0 ){
                tempObjects = new ArrayList<>(originalObjects);
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i=0; i < originalObjects.size(); i++){
                    String text1 = originalObjects.get(i).getText1.toLowerCase();
                    String text2 = originalObjects.get(i).getText2.toLowerCase();
                    String text3 = originalObjects.get(i).getText3.toLowerCase();
                    if(text1.contains(constraint)){
                        tempObjects.add(originalObjects.get(i));
                    } else if (text2.contains(constraint)) {
                        tempObjects.add(originalObjects.get(i));
                    } else if (text3.contains(constraint)){
                        tempObjects.add(originalObjects.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            objects = new ArrayList<>(tempObjects);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Причин может быть миллион и маленькая тележка. Без кода (или по крайней мере схемы кода - так даже лучше) - вам никто здесь не скажет - гадать на кофейной гуще - это на другой форум.

Comment: @Barmaley а какой код нужен именно, адаптера? Просто говорю же, есть такой же адаптер, даже условий там больше, но он запускается в `AppCompatActivity` там все норм, там и элементов больше. И еще, вместо `RecyclerView` ставил `ListView` с `BaseAdapter`, также лагает в фрагменте.

Comment: Начни с адаптера, там видно будет

Comment: @Barmaley добавил код адаптера, только не говорите, что из за многочисленных условий так лагает)) просто такие же условия у другого адаптера, все также, просто там нет `Checkbox` фаворита и соответственно условий фаворита, и он не в фрагменте в `ViewPager` а в `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что там у вас происходит в методах `is/setFav()` - зачем вы каждый раз заново инициализируете `Gson`? Унесите его в приватные члены класса и инициализируйте в конструкторе, да и вообще сама идея парсинга json'а на лету не вызывает восторга - наверное не понимаю всего замысла аффтара :)

Comment: @Barmaley )))))) Да, можно инициализировать в конструкторе, че то я проглядел этот момент)) А парсинг json нужен для фаворитов)) Не хотел я вытаскивать с базы по ID)) лучше в json запихнуть не?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в некэшированном шрифте. Каждый раз, для каждого элемента шрифт подгружается из `Assets` заново.

Попробуйте класс для кэша шрифта:

```
public class TypeFaces {

//---Кэширование шрифта---
private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

public static Typeface get(Context c, String name) {

    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
            String path =  name;
            try {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), path);
                cache.put(name, t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return cache.get(name);
    }
}
}
```

Использование:  `textview.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(Контекст, имя шрифта))`
можно имя по умолчанию задать в самом классе.

Comment: в том и дело, что шрифт можно поменять в настройках и название шрифта сразу не могу написать)
Но я не думаю что именно в шрифте проблема, как говорил выше, такой же адаптер с этими же шрифтами но без `CheckBox` фаворита, норм летает с 200-300 итемами, просто он в `Activity` а этот в `Fragment`

Comment: в свое время проблема с лагами была именно из-за шрифта. Может у вас и не так

Comment: Ок, ща попробую отпишусь))

Comment: вообще воспользуйтесь системами измерения, чтобы посмотреть, что именно перегружает ваше приложение. Навскидку: Android Device Monitor с HierarhyViewer, SystemTracing, Method Profiling; Android Monitor с Memory, CPU и GPU мониторами.

Comment: Эти системы в Android Studio или их отдельно надо устанавливать?

Comment: Да, спасибо! Выручили, в шрифтах было дело)

Comment: это измерители из Студии. Здесь (https://www.udacity.com/course/android-performance--ud825) есть хороший видео-гайд с русскими субтитрами.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте разметку RecyclerView, стоит ли там orientation = "vertical" У меня отсутствие этой строчки приводило к тормозам.